# Особенности работы prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Добрый день,
интересует такой вопрос: возможно ли через метод прототипа получить доступ ко всем объектам которые его наследуют?

Например мы хотим получить все наследующие объекты в один массив:

```
var Question = function(question, answers, correct){
    this.question = question
    this.answers = answers
    this.correct = correct
}

Question.prototype.getAllQuestion = function() {
    //магия
}

var q1 = new Question('Вы славянский шкаф продаете?', ['Таки да', 'А Вы таки кто такой будете?','Канэшна радной прадаем','Тебе надо ты и купи слона'], 3)
var q2 = new Question('Купи слона?',['А слона нет','Нет, брат, с таким настроем ты слона не продашь', 'А я возьму и куплю'], 2)
var q3 = new Question('Почему булочки для хот-догов продают по 8 штук, а сосиски по 10 штук в упаковке?',['ом-ом-ом','Ой всё'], 0)

var all = q1.getAllQuestion() // ['q1','q2','q3']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конструкторе можно запоминать все созданные объекты в статический массив и по запросу возвращать их. Подход рабочий, но из существенных минусов нужно отметить неспособность сборщика мусора автоматически удалить такие объекты, поскольку на них всегда будет ссылка в нашем массиве.

```js
var Question = function(question, answers, correct){
    Question._objects.push(this) // запоминаем только что созданный объект
    this.question = question
    this.answers = answers
    this.correct = correct
}

Question.prototype.getAllQuestion = function() {
    return Question._objects
}

Question._objects = [] // создаём приватное статическое поле

var q1 = new Question('Вы славянский шкаф продаете?', ['Таки да', 'А Вы таки кто такой будете?','Канэшна радной прадаем','Тебе надо ты и купи слона'], 3)
var q2 = new Question('Купи слона?',['А слона нет','Нет, брат, с таким настроем ты слона не продашь', 'А я возьму и куплю'], 2)
var q3 = new Question('Почему булочки для хот-догов продают по 8 штук, а сосиски по 10 штук в упаковке?',['ом-ом-ом','Ой всё'], 0)

var all = q1.getAllQuestion() // ['q1','q2','q3']
console.log(all)
```

Comment: В ES6 есть WeakMap позволяющий решить проблему с сборщиком мусора - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap говорят хорошо уже браузерами поддерживается

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, спасибо за ссылку! Но к сожалению, ни WeakMap, ни WeakSet не дадут реализовать задумку - они не позволяют получить весь список ключей.

Comment: @mymedia а мы можем как-то связать имена переменных которые ссылаются на отдельный объект с тем что мы пушим в Question._objects? И хранить в Question._objects, к примеру, ['q1','q2','q3'].

Comment: @J.Doe, наврядли. Ведь у нас может быть несколько разных имён у объекта: `var q1 = new Question(...); var qT = q1`. Можете попробовать передать "истинное имя" объекта в его конструктор и там запомнить эту строчку.

Comment: @mymedia да, вижу

Comment: @mymedia "истинного" имени будет достаточно, я думаю. А можно как-то передавать левую часть (перед присвоением = ) в правую часть выражения? чтобы не руками вписывать имя переменной которое отдаем?

Comment: @J.Doe, насколько мне известно, такой функциональности нету